# How to write simple SQL query in ASP.NET MVC 4 using linq query

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-like

I want to write following query in ASP.NET MVC 4:

```
select * from Categories where category LIKE '"+result0+"'% ".
```

Is there any reciprocal of `LIKE` in Linq query? How would I get same result in MVC4?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Contains` or `StartsWith`. But what are you using to connect to the database? Are you using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the existence of an `Id` property on a category, you could do something like:

```
Categories.Where(x => x.Id.StartsWith("+result0+"));
```

That will give you an `IEnumerable<Category>` of the categories that meets the "search criteria". If you want a `List<Category>`, you can invoke `ToList()` on the enumerable.